# How do I strconv a string to value int128? currently i'm limited to int64

Tags: go, int

Given, stringvalue := "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"

```
   i, err := strconv.ParseInt(stringvalue, 36, 0)
```

How do I return int128 as my stringvalue will be long enough to return int128?

Comment: There are no int128 in Go. You could use math/big.Int.

Comment: There is no `int128` type in Go. If you need "bigger" than `int64`, consider using [`big.Int`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no Go type `int128`. Use the Go `math/big` package type `Int`.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    z, ok := new(big.Int).SetString("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", 36)
    if ok {
        fmt.Println(z)
        fmt.Println(z.Text(36))
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ln1PswhmK-l

Output:

```
13367494538843734067838845976575
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```